# Javascript innerText - carriage return - regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse some text, and innerText is not outputing the newline characters. I have used white-space, not sure why it's  not working.
The parts variable should have 3 strings in this case, but only getting one string.

I am sure it must be something trivial I am missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  #test1 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id='test1'>1
00:00:13,513 --> 00:00:16,607
a

2
00:00:18,218 --> 00:00:20,516
b

3
00:00:22,355 --> 00:00:24,880
c

  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').innerText;

  <!-- This is not working, parts should have 3 elements, but it cannot find newline character so only has one element -->
  var parts = test1.split(/\r?\n\s+\r?\n/g);
  console.log(parts)
</script>

</html>
```

**Update**

Thanks for the answers, but my string is a little more complicated then abc. I updated the code with a more real example. The regex is taken from a srt file parsing code, and it works if I upload the file, but not when I paste in the text. What's wrong with the html? I am trying to look at regex101 site to see if I can figure this out.

Comment: var parts = test1.split(/\s+/g).filter(n => n);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression isn't properly formatted. `\r?\n\s+\r?\n` means:

- `\r?` - Optionally match a line feed
- `\n` - Match a newline
- `\s+` - Match one or more space characters
- `\r?` - Optionally match a line feed
- `\n` - Match a newline

It requires *at least* a newline, followed by spaces, followed by another newline. But since there aren't two consecutive newlines in the input text, nothing gets split.

To match full lines, I'd just split by `\n` instead, trim each string, and filter out the empty ones:

```js
const text = `
a
b
c
`;
const result = text
  .split('\n')
  .map(str => str.trim())
  .filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);
```

If you wanted to do this with a single regular expression, match `\S` (non-space), followed by as many characters as you can until getting to the end of the line:

```js
const text = `
a
b
c
`;
const result = text.match(/\S(?:.*\S)?/g);
console.log(result);
```

Given the changed text, if you want to match it instead, remove the `\s+` from your regex, since there are no space characters between the two consecutive newlines:

```js
const text = `
1
00:00:13,513 --> 00:00:16,607
a

2
00:00:18,218 --> 00:00:20,516
b

3
00:00:22,355 --> 00:00:24,880
c
`;

console.log(
  text.split(/(?:\r?\n){2}/)
);
```

Comment: Hi CertainPerformance, I almost checked this at the answer, but I am still having problems with the real string (not abc...), can you look at my question, I have updated it with a more real test string. I know that regex in there works with a srt file. Is there anything I need to change in the html to make this regex work? Thanks so much if you can help me. Happy New Year.

Comment: There aren't any spaces between the consecutive newlines, so the `\s+` doesn't match. Remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var parts = test1.split(/\s+/g).filter(n => n);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  #test1 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id='test1'>
    a b c
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').innerText;

  <!-- This is not working, parts should have 3 elements, but it cannot find newline character so only has one element -->
  var parts = test1.split(/\s+/g).filter(n => n);
  console.log(parts)
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi mplungjan, can you look at my question, I have updated it with a more real test string. I know that regex works with a srt file. Is there anything I need to change in the html string to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that with the SRT subtitles file format, it needs a CR (carriage return) for this regex to work.

When you put text in a div, it ignores the CR characters, so they are not detected by innerText, so that's why this regex doesn't work.

When you do:

```
var parts = test1.split('\r')
```

It returns 0 matches, because the html hides the carriage return characters.

I decided to encode my string in base64 and storing it in a input, instead of storing it in div as is.

Comment: Can you show a code sample of your solution?